# Accessing Global Variables within Routes in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, controller

I'm still new to Express, so please bear with me.

What I'm trying to do is store some of my environmental variables in a global variable such that they can be accessed in any route without having to redeclare the variables within each route.

Note that I used the Express Generator to set up the project scaffolding.

Here's a stripped-down example of what I'm trying to do:

**App.js**

```
const express = require('express');

// Load Routes
const inventoryRouter = require('./src/routes/inventory');

// Instantiate Express/Assign App Var
const app = express();

// Set Global Env Vars
app.set('DevUrl', process.env.Dev_URL || null);

// Use Routes
app.use('/inventory', inventoryRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

**Inventory.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Require Inventory Controller
const inventoryController = require('../controllers/inventoryController');

// Inventory Routes
router.get('/', inventoryController.get_inventory);
router.post('/', inventoryController.update_inventory);

module.exports = router;
```

**InventoryController.js**

```
const router = express.Router();

// Store Vars
const LocalRouteVariable = app.get('DevUrl') + 'Some String';

// Rest of Controller Code ...
```

**Question**
"app" is not defined in the controller. So, my question is, how can I get the value of "DevUrl"?

Comment: what is the problem with passing `req` object with function controller ?

Comment: These are environmental variables that I will re-use within my application, but not necessarily within the req object. So, I need to be able to access it outside of the req object. Any thoughts?

Comment: how about using dotenv package

Comment: Yep, I am using Dotenv. Is it best practice to directly add the process.env.something environmental variables directly in the route file or manage all of the them in a config file for use within your routes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `req.app` to access the app instance from inside a controller.

In your case:

**InventoryController.js**

```
export get_inventory = async (req, res, next) =>{
   const devUrl = req.app.get('DevUrl');
   //Controller Logic
}
```